# How to partition an array into multiple arrays with LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

In order to explain the problem I've created a simplified example. In real life the data class is somewhat more complicated. Consider the following data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public Data(string source, string path, string information)
    {
        this.Source = source;
        this.Path = path;
        this.Information = information;
    }           
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }        
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

Now consider the following array:

```
var array = new Data[] {
    new Data("MS", @"c:\temp\img1.jpg", "{a}"),
    new Data("IBM", @"c:\temp\img3.jpg", "{b}"),
    new Data("Google", @"c:\temp\img1.jpg", "{c}"),
    new Data("MS", @"c:\temp\img2.jpg", "{d}"),
    new Data("MS", @"c:\temp\img3.jpg", "{e}"),
    new Data("Google", @"c:\temp\img1.jpg", "{f}"),
    new Data("IBM", @"c:\temp\img2.jpg", "{g}")
};
```

I would like to process the data by partitioning it on the `Path` and sorting each partition on `Source`. The output needs to be like:

```
c:\temp\img1.jpg
"Google":   "{c}"
"IBM":      "{f}"
"MS":       "{a}"

c:\temp\img2.jpg
"IBM":      "{g}"
"MS":       "{d}"

c:\temp\img3.jpg
"IBM":      "{b}"
"MS":       "{e}
```

How can I create these partitions with LINQ?

Here you can play with the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EbKluE

Comment: What should the output types be? A list of Tuples?

Comment: @Marcus no idea [(string,Data[])] I would guess...

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: your sample and your exptected result are unclear. The sample contains two google+c:\temp\img1.jpg but you expect IBM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `OrderBy` and `GroupBy` to sort your items by `Source` and group your ordered items by `Path`:

```
var partitioned = array
    .OrderBy(data => data.Source)
    .GroupBy(data => data.Path);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aD7SXY) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Data[]> result = 
    array.GroupBy(d => d.Path)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.OrderBy(d => d.Source).ToArray());
```

This gives you a dictionary with `Path` as keys. Each value is an array of `Data` that have this `Path` and are sorted by their `Source`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Group-by function of lync.
For your case:

```
var queryImageNames =
    from image in array // <-- Array is your name for the datasource
    group image by image.Path into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;

foreach (var ImageGroup in queryImageNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", nameGroup.Key);
    foreach (var image in ImageGroup )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", image.Source, image.Information);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` to group by the `Path` property:

```
var pathPartitions = array.GroupBy(x => x.Path);

foreach(var grp in pathPartitions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grp.Key);
    var orderedPartition = grp.OrderBy(x => x.Source);
    foreach(var x in orderedPartition )
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{x.Source}\":   \"{x.Information}\"");
}
```

If you want to create a collection you could create a `Tuple<string, Data[]>[]`:

```
Tuple<string, Data[]>[] pathPartitions = array
    .GroupBy(x => x.Path)
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.OrderBy(x => x.Source).ToArray()))
    .ToArray();
```

or a `Dictionary<string, Data[]>`:

```
Dictionary<string, Data[]> pathPartitions = array
    .GroupBy(x => x.Path)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Source).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GroupBy` and do this.

```
    var results = array
        .GroupBy(x=>x.Path)
        .Select(x=>
            new
            { 
                Path =x.Key, 
                values=x.Select(s=> string.Format("{0,-8}:{1}", s.Source, s.Information))
                    .OrderBy(o=>o)
            })
        .ToList();
```

**Output:**

```
c:\temp\img1.jpg
    Google  :{c}
    Google  :{f}
    MS      :{a}
c:\temp\img3.jpg
    IBM     :{b}
    MS      :{e}
c:\temp\img2.jpg
    IBM     :{g}
    MS      :{d}
```

Check this [`fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSPntN)